# Apache proxypass trailing slash / directory issue

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, proxypass

I have a legacy site for a charity running on an old Apache 1.3 instance, behind Apache 2 running proxypass. When a request comes to example.com, Apache 2 sends it internally to localhost:8080 which works fine.

**The problem:**

**example.com/blog/** works but **example.com/blog** (no trailing slash) does not. The URL it changes to in Chrome is **example.com:8080/blog/** which doesn't exist.

The same is true for all other directories.

Apache 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache 1:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /usr/www/html/
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)$
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought a simple solution would be to add a rewriterule in either virtualhost but I've not had any success despite many attempts. I think a key issue is it's wrongly looking on example.com:8080 when the slash isn't there. It would be great if anyone can help me out, ask me any additional info that would be useful.

Comment: A trace of exactly what gets sent back and forth between your Apaches, and Apache and the browser, in the erroneous case, would be handy.  I still think there's a URL rewriting issue going on here somewhere.

Comment: @womble How would you recommend I produce a trace? I have checked the logs and nothing is appearing in access or error for either virtualhost.

Comment: tcpdump would work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see no `ProxyPassReverse` or `mod_proxy_html` directives in your config; the lack of `ProxyPassReverse`, specifically, is likely to be the cause of your issue as the backend Apache is sending a redirect to the slashful URL, but has it's internal name in the Location: header, and without `ProxyPassReverse` the frontend Apache is just letting that internal URL leak.

`mod_proxy_html` is for the equivalent issues, but in HTML rather than HTTP headers.  It's also worth using, unless you're *really* sure nobody's going to go putting a full URL in the HTML (which, for any dynamic webapp, is a bad bet).

Comment: Thanks - I have added ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/ and restarted the server, unfortunately the same issue remains and it's trying to load up example.com:8080/blog/ when accessing example.com/blog - I've added the new line to original post.